# Return the thumbnail meta data for getter and setter

Tags: custom-post-types, php

So I'm wanting to target the thumbnail but I'm not able to find it successfully. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

var_dump(profile):
[image]

var_dump($thumbnail):
[image]

Could anyone point me in the right direction to target thumbnail?

**Here is my class**:

```
class Profile
{

    // Private variables to hold data
    private $bio;
    private $thumbnail;

    // Initialize the object's id property
    public function __construct($post)
    {
        $this->set_bio($post->post_content);
        $this->set_thumbnail($this->thumbnail);
    }

    // Create the init method that calls the registered post type and pass in a id parameter
    public static function init($id)
    {
        $post = get_post($id);
        var_dump($post);

        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id);
        var_dump($thumbnail);

        $profile = new Profile($post);

        // Call to return the profile so that `Profile::init($id)` works.
        return $profile;
    }

    public function set_bio($bio)
    {
        $this->bio = $bio;
    }

    public function get_bio()
    {
        return $this->bio;
    }

    public function set_thumbnail($thumbnail)
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;
    }

    public function get_thumbnail()
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you constructor to this

```
public function __construct($post)
{
    $this->set_bio($post->post_content);
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
    $this->set_thumbnail($thumbnail);
}
```

and remove thumbnail code from init method.

Comment: Works like a charm - Thanks @vitauts